# Big ugly icons in notification area

Tags: 11.10, gnome, icons, gnome-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10, with Gnome classic DE and Ambiance theme.
I really like it, but one thing is driving me crazy - there are big ugly icons in notification area.

I tried with different icon packs without success.

How can I change their size, to have ~height as Skype and WIFI icon?

[image]

Comment: please look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic   - instructions on how to change your icons back to ubuntu mono icons are in the main answer.

Answer (score -1):

Well thats because you changed the theme, try to change another theme. The icons sets are different from theme to theme.

Comment: I tried with installing various icon sets and its same. I really like Ambiance theme and would not like to change it :)